# Not able to pass eval to javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have following imagebutton in gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ControlStyle-CssClass="smallTxt"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="smallTxt">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/yellow_arrow.gif" ID="imgbtnsearch"
                     OnClientClick="javascript:setCustID('<% Eval(idCustomer)%>');return false;" />


                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Through this image button I am calling a Javascript function. See code below.

```
 function setCustID(cid) {
        alert(cid);
        ShowHideControl('ctl04_divEdit');
        document.getElementById('ctl04_hdnIdCustomer').value = cid;


    }
```

When I run this, instead of getting `Eval(idCustomer)` result in figures (in alert box of javascript), I am getting:

```
<% Eval(idCustomer).toString()%>
```

When I put # while passing parameter as : <%#Eval(idCustomer)%>

```
OnClientClick="javascript:setCustID('<%#Eval(idCustomer)%>');return false;"
```

Function alerts:

```
<%#Eval(idCustomer)%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The move with `#` was the right one. Besides not to get lost with quotation (as I did before the edit) call `string.Format` to deal with js expression:

```
OnClientClicking='<%# string.Format("javascript:setCustID({0});return false;", Eval("idCustomer")) %>'
```

Also make sure to wrap function parameter with single quotes if this is a string. Leave it as it is if this is an integer though.

Comment: Thanxd, this was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry ,As I am not not so good in ASP,
but for Eval: I think it should not pass as String : "Eval(string)" instead this you may use Eval("string").